# How can I edit a binary image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, binary

How can I display and edit binary images in PHP? 
For example, how can I edit the image below bit-by-bit in PHP?

[image: Firefox Logo]

(Click image to enlarge.)

Comment: You mean, pixel by pixel, correct? The [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is the most popular way to do this.

Comment: yes, pixel by pixel. you can give me some examples?

Comment: You'll be interested in `imagesetpixel()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php it's got a good example

Comment: thanks Pekka! please more examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific function calls that you'll need to use depend largely on what exactly you'd like to do to the image. However, PHP uses the GD library, which covers an extensive range of image manipulation abilities.

Here are some tutorials to help you get started:

- http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/1624-php-tutorial-getting-know-gd.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
- http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/gd_library.htm

Comment: how can i display binary from image? for example 001001100011000

Comment: If you just want to do that, you can use file_get_contents to read binary files.